# From relational database to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am beginner in NoSql databases (I use mongodb), I need your help to translate my schema from relational to NoSql schema.

[image: relational schema]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main nosql concept is different from the traditional sql (relational ) model. It does not means that's you can't do relations between nosql entities but you should care about your use cases before choosing a nosql database.

In sql , relations are generally done by ids. You can achieve the same with a nosql database. 
In nosql, an entry is often call a document. In a document, you could refer to an other doc by given it's id key for example ( as you do already with user_id, group_id .. ).

I suggest you to read the mongoDB doc about data modeling https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

It could be a nice introduction to what you want to do